# How to sign data with certificate on web page

Tags: certificate, signing

**The Stage**
I'm working on a web application to enable trade of assets between different parties.
The different parties are known to me, and are not too many.
I record each transaction of an asset from one party to another in a database (sql server). I've stripped down database access as much as I can, and parties have to identify themselves by usernames and passwords to initiate transactions. Communication from web to api will of course be secure (https).

**The Problem**
These measures leaves me pretty confident that the stored transactions are authentic, but of course the parties of the transactions does not necessarily trust that I (or anyone else with sa password) haven't tampered with the data or created fake transactions.

**My thinking**
So I figure I need something to be able to prove the authenticity of such a transaction. 
Maybe a signature from the party who is giving away their asset? A signature that I can store along with the signed transaction? In that case, the signer needs a private key and I think *certificates* is a way do this, right? I don't know of any way to access certificates installed on a computer from a web page though so the web page would have to launch a locally installed application to do the actual signing, because the locally installed application could access the certificate, and the signing party have trust in this application to sign the actual untampered-with transaction.

1. Is this a feasible solution?
2. How should certificates be distributed? I guess they should be issued from a CA that both I and the party trust?

Comment: Do you need to use a trusted CA (e.g verisign) or do you want to create and distribute the certificates yourself?

Comment: I am not completely sure. Let's say we end up in court and the signee of a transaction claims that he didn't sign it. If the certificate was issued by myself (the system author), and I have the power to issue new certificates, I guess it will be impossible for me to prove that I didn't create the certificate and signed the transaction myself?

Comment: Distributing certificates does not imply that you have the user's private key, which is the one used for the signature. The key pair is generated on the user's device, and the certificate is issued by the CA using the public key sent by user, so the CA can not create fake signatures. (Some CAs generate the certificate and store it in their HSMs, but this is another question). Using 'trusted' CA avoids this kind of legal questions from users, so I asked you if your users trust you or you should trust a third party.

Comment: The difference is that if you use your own CA you define the process of issuing certificates, but if they are issued by a third party, the distribution process is out of your control. The architecture of your system can be completely different